# XJS value should be either an expression or a quoted XJS text

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to programming, and started doing exercises I found

I have been trying to build this [exercise](https://medium.com/learning-new-stuff/building-your-first-react-js-app-d53b0c98dc#.tq8aqih9z), but no I keep getting this error, help?

Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 16: XJS value should be either an expression or a quoted XJS text(…)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!-- DOCTYPE HTML -->
<html>
<head>
<title>Your First React Project</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script src="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t39.3284-6/12512166_196876483993243_981414082_n.js"></script>
<script src="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t39.3284-6/12512184_1664789273772979_614489084_n.js"></script>
<script src="http://dragon.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t39.3284-6/10734305_1719965068228170_722481775_n.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx">
/*Add your React code here*/


var DATA = {
    name: 'John Smith',
    imgURL: 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/',
    hobbyList: ['coding', 'writing', 'skiing']
};


var App = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
        <div>
          <Profile name=this.props.profileData.name imgURL=this.props.profileData.imgURL/>
          <Hobbies hobbyList=this.props.profileData.hobbyList/>
        </div>
    );
  }
});

var Profile = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
      <h3> {this.props.name} </h3>
      <img src={this.source.imgURL} />

      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Hobbies = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var hobbies = this.props.hobbyList.map(function(hobby,index) {

      return (
        <div>
          <h5>My Hobbies:</h5>
          <ul>{hobbies}</ul>
        </div>
      )
    }
  );

  }
});


ReactDom.render(<App profileData={DATA}/>, document.getElementById('content'));


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, a couple of things:

1. You forgot the curly brackets around some props. So instead of `<Profile name=this.props.profileData.name />`, you want `<Profile name={this.props.profileData.name} />`. That was causing the error you've mentioned in the headline of this question.
2. Not sure why you've used `this.source` in the Profile component. That returns undefined. Instead, use the prop that you've already passed along (`this.props.imgURL`).
3. In the Hobbies component your iteration isn't 100% working. Try to only iterate the `<li>` elements (your hobbies) and then put them in the `ul` tag below.

I've fixed these parts of your code and hope that that will help. It's only small things, nothing major. Have fun!

```js
var DATA = {
  name: 'John Smith',
  imgURL: 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/',
  hobbyList: ['coding', 'writing', 'skiing']
};


var App = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
      <Profile name={this.props.profileData.name} imgURL={this.props.profileData.imgURL}/>
      <Hobbies hobbyList={this.props.profileData.hobbyList}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Profile = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <div>
      <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
      <img src={this.props.imgURL} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Hobbies = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var hobbies = this.props.hobbyList.map(function(hobby, index) {
      return <li>{hobby}</li>;
    });
    return (
      <div>
      <h5>My Hobbies:</h5>
      <ul>{hobbies}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(<App profileData={DATA}/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Fabian! I really dont know where I got the source from, and i should have been more aware with the {}, and the hobbies one suddenly looks so clear, shouldnt have missed that

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.